# change local time to another timezone javascript

Tags: javascript, timezone

I'm using a script  that grab a  json informations from a  Web App using their API and my ajax code, but if something in  the Web app change, I still grab the old  informations, because we have difference in Time Zone. So if I add 11 hours in My computer I get the new Informations.
So it's possible to change local time to another timezone using javascript ? Thanks.

### UPDATE

**I'm using ajax with Javascript, not jQuery**

```
function getInfos(url) {

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("GET", url, true);
    oReq.send(null);
    oReq.responseType = "text";
    oReq.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (oReq.readyState == 4)
        {
            var resp = JSON.parse(oReq.responseText)
            // Do Something with Data
        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post a bit of code? Presumably you're sending the current date in your request, so you could modify that?

Comment: Shown code does not perform any date manipulation at all. In fact, it doesn't even send request data :-?

Comment: I would try very hard to do the time zone date manipulations on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [timesonze-js](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js).  According to their documentation you should initialize it like this:

```
timezoneJS.timezone.zoneFileBasePath = '/path/to/your/tz/folder';
timezoneJS.timezone.init();
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
var date = new timezoneJS.Date('04/30/2014', 'America/Chicago');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exists a function to change timezone

javascript automatically takes the time zone of your computer

one way would
Use UTC() method

after

add or subtract the minutes of difference

with this you will have the time in any time zone

use gettimezoneoffset to get the minutes of difference